# HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated() is getting called twice when Spring MVC application is starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-session

I have registered `HttpSessionListener` implemented class in `web.xml` and when application is starting, `sessionCreated()` method is getting called two times. When I logged out from application, `sessionDestroyed()` is calling and then after again `sessionCreated()` is calling. Why it is so?

```
public class SessionManager implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {     
           System.out.println("Session Creation called!!..");     
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
           System.out.println("Session Destruction called!!..");   
    }
}
```

Output:

When application is starting, it prints "Session Creation called!!.." two times. When I logged out, it prints first as "Session Destruction called!!.." and second as "Session Creation called!!..".

Comment: I think `sessionCreated()` method get called when a new session get generated. so when you logged out, `session.invalidate()` get called and after that a new session get created for annonymouns user.

Comment: It should not happen like this. Can you help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you successfully log in to your application, prior to creating a new authenticated session the old anonymous session is destroyed. The similar thing also occurs on log out, when authenticated session is first destroyed, a new anonymous is created. This is consistent with the the scenario you have described.

To verify which exact sessions are being created and destroyed, improve your logging to also include session id. For example:

```
public class SessionManager implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println("session created: " + httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println("session destroyed: " + httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId());
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, what you pointed out to keep a track of the session id's, but for the case when I'm trying to get a  count of the number of online users, the value I get is not accurate, can you help how this can be sorted out?